# Перебор цифр без создания новой строки

Tags: python, консоль, print

Есть подобный цикл:

```
for i in range(1, 25765):
 print(i)
```

Тоесть перебирать цифры, но как сделать, чтобы каждый раз не создавать новую строку.(На что можно заменить `print()` )

Правильно:

```
3 of 25765
```

Не правильно:

```
1 of 25765
2 of 25765
3 of 25765
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение, основанное на комментарии @andreymal

```
print(i, end='\r')
```

Answer (score 0):

Сделайте import system.
Добавьте строку кода os.system('cls') #(если выдаёт ошибку попробуйте os.system('clear')) после строки print(i).